# load() PHP after element

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-load

Because of certain reasons i need to load a PHP file via jquery (at the final point it will be responsible for calling wordpress dynamic sidebar but I cannot execute php inside jquery). What I have right now is:

```
$('#pa_kategoria-cenowa').after('<div class="product-variation-desc"><div id="5" class="box">CENA 5 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean semper egestas sodales. In commodo massa eget lectus eleifend, nec dictum sapien laoreet. </div><div id="10" class="box">CENA 10 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean semper egestas sodales. In commodo massa eget lectus eleifend, nec dictum sapien laoreet. </div><div id="15" class="box">CENA 15 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean semper egestas sodales. In commodo massa eget lectus eleifend, nec dictum sapien laoreet. </div></div>');
```

my php file is called: **load-widgets.php**

that's why loading function should looks like that:

```
.load('load-widgets.php');
```

content of the PHP file will be following:

```
<div class="product-variation-desc"><div id="5" class="box">CENA 5 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean semper egestas sodales. In commodo massa eget lectus eleifend, nec dictum sapien laoreet. </div><div id="10" class="box">CENA 10 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean semper egestas sodales. In commodo massa eget lectus eleifend, nec dictum sapien laoreet. </div><div id="15" class="box">CENA 15 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean semper egestas sodales. In commodo massa eget lectus eleifend, nec dictum sapien laoreet. </div></div>
```

but I have no clue how to combine it together. I've tried:

```
$('#pa_kategoria-cenowa').after().load('load-widgets.php');
```

but it doesnt work. How to achieve that?

Comment: What you have should work fine. Check the console for errors in the AJAX request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exisiting Code should work. Check for errors in Console. If that doesn't resolve, try below AJAX snippet.

```
$.get("load-widgets.php", function(data){ // Loads content into the 'data' variable.
   $("#pa_kategoria-cenowa").after(data); 
});
```

Comment: works! the only issue (error 500) is when I'm implementing php code inside my php file. Why is that? im calling a dynamic sidebar via that file..

Comment: @PawełSkaba `when I'm implementing php code inside my php file.` I didn't get your question.

Comment: in load-widgets.php I have a code: <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'variation-description' ); ?> and its causing the error.

Comment: @PawełSkaba What is the content in `load-widgets.php`. Can you post the code if it's minimal.

Comment: just like i mentioned - the only code is:<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'variation-description' ); ?>

Comment: @PawełSkaba Where is `dynamic_sidebar` function definition then??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110834/discussion-between-jenson-m-john-and-pawel-skaba).